# Диапазон дат недели

Tags: mysql, sql

Есть таблица objects, где хранятся данные по объектам недвижимости.
Необходимо с помощью запроса рассчитать новое поле, в котором будет отображаться
диапазон дат с понедельника по воскресенье, в который попадает дата создания
объекта (например, “2020-11-16 - 2020-11-22”)

```
create table objects(
   object_id int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY ,
city_id int not null ,
price int ,
area_total int ,
status varchar(50) ,
class varchar(50) ,
action varchar(50) ,
date_create timestamp,
FOREIGN KEY(city_id) references avg_price_square_city(city_id)
);
```

Данные в таблице:

```
 INSERT INTO objects (object_id, city_id, price, area_total, status, class, action, date_create) VALUES (1, 1, 4600000, 72, 'active', 'Вторичная', 'Продажа', '2022-05-06 21:49:34');
    INSERT INTO objects (object_id, city_id, price, area_total, status, class, action, date_create) VALUES (2, 2, 5400000, 84, 'active', 'Вторичная', 'Продажа', '2022-05-06 21:49:35');
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

В запросе нужно вывести два поля: номер объекта и диапазон, в который попадает дата его
создания.Каким способом это возможно сделать?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT object-id, CONCAT(DATE(date_create-WEEKDAY(date_create)),'-',DATE(date_create-WEEKDAY(date_create))+INTERVAL 6 DAY)) AS 'интервал' 
FROM objects;
```

По порядку:

`WEEKDAY(date_create)` даёт порядковый номер дня в неделе.

Вычитая его из даты создания  получаем пн. DATE приводит дату со временем в нужный формат (без времени).

Прибавляя к получившемуся пн 6 дней, выходим на конец нужной недели. И ,с помощью CONCAT, приводим столбец к нужному виду, используя разделитель '-'. Вместо него можно взять пробел или любой другой разделитель. Удачи!